# Writing to file using VBA Print statement - without space delimiters

Tags: string, ms-access, vba

In making a file with MS Access to be used with QuickBooks IIF, I need a tab delimited file, with no white spaces in between the identifiers. I have this output file opening and all goes into the file, but with **spaces** on either side of the strings. Below is what I started with:

```
Print #1, "!TRNS", vbTab, "TRNSID", vbTab, "TRNSTYPE", vbTab, "DATE" 'etc...
```

and I modified it to:

```
Print #1, "!TRNS", vbTab, Trim(strTRNSID), vbTab, Trim("TRNSTYPE"), vbTab, "DATE" 'etc...
```

The spaces are not eliminated in the output file file with the trim function; so I mean the strings that are sent with tabs still have spaces on either side of the strings.

How do I get rid of those spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about concatenating the strings before you pass them to the Print command?

```
Print #1, "!TRNS" & vbTab & Trim(strTRNSID) & vbTab & Trim("TRNSTYPE") & vbTab & "DATE"
```

You'll need to make sure each item is converted to a string, but otherwise that should be OK I think

Comment: Gromit, that's it! Cheese! We'll go somewhere where there's cheese!